# Crash on Favorite Feature

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, favorite

I'm working on implementing a "Favorite" feature in my app.

The idea is the "favorite" a page to quickly go back to it.

Here's what I have tried:

```
// In the Detail View Controller
- (void)favoriteRecipe
{
    NSUserDefaults * prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableArray * favoriteDrinks;

    if ([prefs objectForKey:@"favoriteDrink"] == nil)
    {
        NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [prefs setObject:array forKey:@"favoriteDrink"];
    }
    NSMutableArray * tempArray = [[prefs objectForKey:@"favoriteDrink"] mutableCopy];
    favoriteDrinks = tempArray;

    NSString * drinkNameString = self.drinkNameLabel.text;
    NSString * ingredientString = self.ingredientLabel.text;
    NSArray * favArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:drinkNameString, ingredientString, nil];
    [favoriteDrinks addObject:favArray];
    isFavorite = YES;
    [prefs setObject:favoriteDrinks forKey:@"favoriteDrink"];

    if (isFavorite == YES)
    {
        //Change the image 
    }
}
```

In my FavoriteViewController I have a table set up. I want the name to show, and then selecting it will go to that page.

I am using Parse.com as my back-end, so I have just one Detail View Controller that changes based on the item.

Here's where I try to go back to the Detail View Controller but crash:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    RecipeDetailViewController * recipeDetail = [[RecipeDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RecipeDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    PFObject * favObjects = [self.favArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSArray * ingredients = [favObjects objectForKey:@"ingredients"]; //Crashes Here

    recipeDetail.ingredientArray = ingredients;

    NSString * nameString = [favObjects objectForKey:@"recipe_name"];
    recipeDetail.nameString = nameString;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:recipeDetail animated:YES];
}
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe76bea0
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does the crash say in the error console?

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you're trying to call the objectForKey on an array. It seems that what you get in return from calling `[self.favArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` is not what you're expecting to get. You're expecting a PFObject, but it seems you're getting an array (if indeed that IS the line that causes the crash).

Have a look in debugger to see what is actually returned from `[self.favArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`.

Comment: It is returning all of the information from the view I have favorited. I may need to do a query on each end and store the objectId from Parse.com. Right now I'm not having users sign in, but I still want this feature to be unique per user. Thoughts?

Comment: To have it unique pr user, you need to differentiate between the users. So create a Favorites class in parse that has a user column and a recipes column that is an array where you store pointers to the recipes the user has favorited.

Comment: To note, users are not creating accounts in this app. Will I still be able to use this route? Any other suggested routes?

Comment: Then you need to differentiate users another way, i.e. with NSString *uuid = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];  This must then be stored locally to be used every time your app contacts parse. Replace my suggested pointer to the user with this string.